# no grouping separator char for DecimalFormat

Tags: java

`DecimalFormat` uses `','` as the default grouping separator character.

What is the correct way to tell DecimalFormat that we don't want any grouping separator character? I currently use symbols.setGroupingSeparator('\0'), and it seems to work,
but it looks ugly.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('\0');

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
Number result = df.parse("44,000.0", pp);   // this should fail, as I don't want any grouping separatator char.
if (pp.getIndex() != input.length())
   throw new Exception("invalid number: " + input, 0);
```

What is the correct way to tell DecimalFormat that we don't want any grouping separator char?

Comment: Is It a bad practice to set the group separator to '\0'?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Turn off grouping by calling [`setGroupingUsed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setGroupingUsed%28boolean%29):

```
df.setGroupingUsed(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`setGroupingUsed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setGroupingUsed%28boolean%29) method, but that won't make the format reject the number, it will just stop parsing at the first separator. Number parsing with formats will ignore everything after the first invalid character.