# DecimalFormat gives differfent result in Oracle Java 1.7 and IBM java 1.6

Tags: java, decimalformat, ibm-jdk

lets have a simple test code:

```
public static void main(String ... arg)
{
    double d = 4000.0;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
}
```

In Oracle/SUN java output is (with space):

> 4 000

But in IBM java i got:

> 4,000

My java:

> java version "1.7.0_51" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_51-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

IBM java:

> java -version  java version "1.6.0"  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   (build pap6460_26sr7ifix-20131203_01(SR7+IX90131+IV52621))  IBM J9 VM
>   (build 2.6, JRE 1.6.0 AIX ppc64-64 Compressed References
>   20131011_170248 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)  J9VM -
>   R26_Java626_SR7_20131011_1221_B170248  JIT  - r11.b05_20131003_47443 
>   GC   - R26_Java626_SR7_20131011_1221_B170248_CMPRSS  J9CL -
>   20131011_170248)  JCL  - 20131015_01

Anyone have idea why is this? Is it because 1.6/1.7 difference? Or maybe its locale problem, probably not.

Comment: Locale could be the issues, what is your local in the Oracle JVM?

Comment: actually in both Locale.getDefault() it prints en_US

Comment: not sure, but what are the output for `ibm.system.encoding` and `sun.jnu.encoding`

Comment: This is different, oracle is Cp1250 and IBM is ISO8859-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found probably solution here [no grouping separator char for DecimalFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035701/no-grouping-separator-char-for-decimalformat)

Its so simple :)

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
```

apparently ibm and oracle uses different default group separator. Dunno why

Comment: Usually the space separator is a non-breaking space though. (`\u00a0`)